# Servicestack Windows Universal Social Authentication

Tags: authentication, oauth, servicestack

I am trying to implement social authentication from a c# client within a windows universal 8.1 app. When I post to the auth provider .../googleoauth for example the client fails. Fiddler is showing a 302 redirect so the deserialization fails n the response. The authentication flow works if I use a browser so I think everything is configured correctly, but of course could have missed something. If anyone has any insight or an example using social authentication providers from a c# client that would be much appreciated.
ian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OAuth flow requires a browser to work in order to redirect the user to the remote OAuth website where they can approve access. So you'll need to launch the url in a WebView then capture the [Session cookies](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Sessions#permanent-and-temporary-session-ids) after the user approves your application and is redirected back to your website.

The [TechStacks Auth](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/TechStacksAuth) Example demonstrates this strategy using Xamarin.Auth component for Xamarin.Android.

Comment: Ok that makes more sense thanks. So out of the webview is it okay to add all of the cookies or should I only be 'ss-id', 'ss-pid'... explicitly? Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @ticky74 only the `ss-id`,`ss-pid` and `ss-opt` are needed.

Comment: I can't seem to get the cookie/session values set into the jsonhttpserviceclient. Does anyone have a good example of this using  windows universal libraries. I have looked throught TechStacks.Auth and I can't seem to get the cookie container configured properly. Any subsequent calls to dtos that require authentication with the client fail.

Comment: @ticky74 I don't have any examples using UWP but try using `RememberMe=true` if you're not already.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else was looking for a sample in UWP. This seems to be working for me. The CreateCookieContainer method for the most part simply loops through the cookies and adds them to a new container that is returned. Thanks @mythz again for the awesome work and support in ServiceStack

```
            // Grab auth cookies from callback uri
            var cookies = _httpFilter.CookieManager.GetCookies(uri);
            var authCookies = cookies.AsEnumerable().Where(x => new[] {"ss-id", "ss-pid", "ss-opt"}.Contains(x.Name))
                .Select(x => new Cookie(x.Name, x.Value, x.Path, x.Domain)).ToArray();

            string sessionId = null;
            var cookieJar = CreateCookieContainer(authCookies, uri, ref sessionId);

            // Store the tokens for autologin
            await DataServiceFactory.Instance.StoreSingletonSetAsync(authCookies);

            // Set auth on the current client
            _serviceClient.CookieContainer = cookieJar;
            _serviceClient.SessionId = sessionId;
```